# Как сделать адаптивность сайта?

Tags: html, css, responsive, css-grid, адаптивность

Проблема с адаптивностью сайта. Я новичок, поэтому не особо разбираюсь как правильно писать адаптивность. Все работает на определенных размерах экрана, но как только немного уменьшить, сразу все ломается, подскажите как сделать адекватную адаптивность сайта. Сайт на хостинке - http://b70810gn.beget.tech/

```css
/*BLOCK_3*/
.row-block_3 {
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
     margin: 0;
}
.row2-block_3{
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    margin: 30px 0;
}
.ZAGOLOVOK_WHITE {
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 42px;
    color: white;
    margin: 80px 0 60px 0;}
.card-logo{
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.44);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.44);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.44);}
.card-img-top{
    width: 60% !important;}
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    justify-items: end;
    grid-auto-rows: 200px;}
.grid-container > div {
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 30px;}
@media (max-width: 1280px){
    .block_5_text{
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    .icon-block_5 {
        width: 20px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1100px){
    .block_5_text{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .icon-block_5 {
        width: 20px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1024px){
    .card-product-img{
        width: 60%;
    }
    .card-product-img-bitcoin{
        width: 80px;
    }
    .card-logo-prod {
        width: 160px;
        height: 120px;
    }
    .container-nav {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .card-product {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    .ZAGOLOVOK_1_1 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .ZAGOLOVOK_1_2 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .ZAGOLOVOK_2_1 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .ZAGOLOVOK_2_2 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .ZAGOLOVOK_WHITE {
        margin: 60px 0 40px 0;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 992px){
    .navbar_img_logo {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .container-nav {
        max-width: 1000px !important;
    }
    .container-nav {
        max-width: 1000px;
    }
    .icon-block_5 {
        display: contents;
        margin-left: -10px;
        width: 15px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .text-center-my{
        text-align: -webkit-center;
    }
    .list-unstyled{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #footer h5{
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    .BLOCK_1_CONTENT {
        width: 100%;}
    .ZAGOLOVOK_1_2 {
        font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;}
    .ZAGOLOVOK_1_1 {
        font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: lighter;
        color: white;}
    .ZAGOLOVOK_2_1 {
        font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: lighter;
        color: white;}
    .ZAGOLOVOK_2_2 {
        font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;}
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
    .bazis-margin-768px
    .marginleft-768px {
        margin-left: 256px;
    }
    .block-6-margintop{
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .margintop-768px{
        margin-top: -120px !important;
    }
    .row-block_3 {
        justify-content: end;
        text-align: -webkit-center;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .row2-block_3{
        justify-content: end;
        text-align: -webkit-center;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
        margin: 30px 0;
    }
    .cashterminal-margin-768px{
        margin-top: -120px;
    }
    .walletone-margin-768px{
        margin-left: 256px;
        margin-top: 30px; 
    }
    .bitcoin-margin-768px{
        margin-top: -150px;
        
    }
    .card-prod-margin-top {
        margin-top: 30px; 
    }
    .card-title{
        font-size: 50px;
    }
    .card-subtitle_1{
        font-size: 35px;
    }
    .card-title-text_1{
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .card-text_1{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .card-logo{width: 200px;}
    .ZAGOLOVOK_WHITE {
        margin: 40px 0 40px 0;
    }
    .bottom_text {
        font-size: 23px;
        font-family: 'Calibri';
        font-weight: lighter;
    }
    .list-unstyled{
        font-size: 12px
    }
    #footer h5 {
        font-size: 22px;
        padding-left: 0;
        border-left: transparent;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;}
    .BLOCK_1_CONTENT {
        width: 90%;}
    h1{
        line-height: 0.9 !important;}
    .glav-img{
        width: 80%}
    .ZAGOLOVOK_1_2 {
        font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;}
    .ZAGOLOVOK_1_1 {
        font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: lighter;
        color: white;}
    .ZAGOLOVOK_2_1 {
        font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: lighter;
        color: white;}
    .ZAGOLOVOK_2_2 {
        font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;}
        
    /*BLOCK_6*/
    .card-logo-customers {
        width: 200px;}
    .img-customers{width: 90%}
    .block_6_text{
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: 'Calibri';
        font-weight: lighter;}
    .card-768px{
        display: grid;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 576px){
    .container {
        max-width: 600px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 550px){
    .ZAGOLOVOK_WHITE{font-size: 30px}
}
@media (max-width: 425px){
    .bazis-margin-425px {margin-top: -200px !important;}
    .kaztranscom-margintop-425px{
        margin-left: 213px;
        margin-top: -200px !important;
    }
    .nomad-margintop-425px {
        margin-top: -200px;
    }
    .marginleft-768px {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
    .margintop-768px {
        margin-top: 30px !important;
    }
    .row {
        margin-top: 0 !important;
    }
    .row-block_3 {
        justify-content: end;
        text-align: -webkit-center;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .row2-block_3{
        justify-content: end;
        text-align: -webkit-center;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
        margin: 30px 0;
    }
    .cashterminal-walle-425px {
        margin-top: -150px !important;
        margin-left: 202px;
    }
    .margin-walle-425px {
        margin-top: -150px !important;
    }
    .margin-yandex-425px{
        margin-top: -150px !important;
    }
    .cashterminal-margin-768px{
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    .walletone-margin-768px{
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-top:0; 
    }
    .margin-425px{
        margin-top: 30px;  
    }
    .block_5_text{
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .card-logo {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }
    .card_priemushestva{
        height: 200px;
        width: 160px;
    }
    .card-product-img{
        width: 50%;
    }
    .card-product-img-bitcoin{
        width: 60px
    }
    h1 {line-height: 0.7 !important;}
    h2 {line-height: 0.8 !important;}
    .ZAGOLOVOK_1_1 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .ZAGOLOVOK_1_2 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .ZAGOLOVOK_2_1 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .ZAGOLOVOK_2_2 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .block-center {
        display: grid;
        justify-content: center
    }
}

@media (max-width: 375px) {
    .ZAGOLOVOK_BLUE{
        font-size: 38px;
    }
    .cashterminal-walle-425px {
        margin-top: -150px !important;
        margin-left: 187px;
    }
    .kaztranscom-margintop-425px{
        margin-left: 187px;
        margin-top: -200px !important;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .cashterminal-walle-425px {
        margin-left: 160px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!--BLOCK_3-->
    <div class="BLOCK_1_BG_IMG">
        <div class="container" style="max-width: 1366px;">
            <div class="row" style="display: grid; justify-content: center;">
                <div class="col-xl-12" id="sposoby-oplaty">
                    <h2 class="ZAGOLOVOK_WHITE">Один продукт - 10 способов оплаты</h2>
                </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="row row-block_3">
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 block-center">
                    <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
                        <img src="images/visa.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 block-center">
                    <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
                        <img src="images/mastercard.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 block-center margin-425px">
                    <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
                        <img src="images/beeline.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 block-center card-prod-margin-top margin-425px">
                    <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
                        <img src="images/onay.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 block-center card-prod-margin-top margin-425px">
                    <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
                        <img src="images/qiwi.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row2-block_3">
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 block-center margin-425px">
                    <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
                        <img src="images/WebMoney.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 block-center margin-425px margin-yandex-425px">
                    <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
                        <img src="images/Yandex.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 block-center bitcoin-margin-768px margin-425px">
                    <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
                        <img src="images/bitcoin.png" class="card-product-img-bitcoin card-img-top" style="width: 40% !important">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 block-center walletone-margin-768px margin-425px margin-walle-425px">
                    <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
                        <img src="images/wallet one.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 block-center cashterminal-margin-768px margin-425px cashterminal-walle-425px">
                    <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
                        <img src="images/CASH TERMINAL.png" class="card-product-img">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/349484/

Comment: Раздел наши клиенты лучше сделать через грид - не придётся вводить медиазапрос

Comment: @makcim512 не получается сделать так, чтоб мои блоки автоматически выравнивались, приходится добавлять кучу медиазапросов. Подвигайте края браузера и вы поймете о чем я)

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко можете отправить ссылку на сайт, на который я бы мог ориентироваться?

Comment: @KRCNV Почему они должны выравниваться? Правильно для этого и нужны медиа запросы)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.card-logo {
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
}

.card-img-top {
  width: 60% !important;
}

article {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, auto));
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xl-12" id="sposoby-oplaty">
  <h2 class="ZAGOLOVOK_WHITE">Один продукт - 10 способов оплаты</h2>
</div>

<article>
  <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
    <img src="images/visa.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
  </div>


  <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
    <img src="images/mastercard.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
  </div>


  <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
    <img src="images/beeline.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
  </div>

  <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
    <img src="images/onay.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
  </div>


  <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
    <img src="images/qiwi.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
  </div>


  <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
    <img src="images/WebMoney.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
  </div>

  <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
    <img src="images/Yandex.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
  </div>

  <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
    <img src="images/bitcoin.png" class="card-product-img-bitcoin card-img-top" style="width: 40% !important">
  </div>


  <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
    <img src="images/wallet one.png" class="card-product-img card-img-top">
  </div>

  <div class="card card-logo card-logo-prod">
    <img src="images/CASH TERMINAL.png" class="card-product-img">
  </div>
</article>
```

Вот. Удалил кучу ненужных блоков